# fitting multiple curves to set of points

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

Can we fit multiple second order curves to a set a points in R^2 space ? Let's say we have set of points in the above mentioned space . I know that there could be at max 10 curves that can be fit in that space . I want to have the best possible fit to those points using arbitrary number of curves .

Comment: Could you please edit your question so we can have a clearer view of what you're asking? A picture could really help too.

Comment: @AdrienNK : Here is the image http://imgur.com/flIwus2 .I want to fit two quadratic curves to it .

Comment: Seems to me that this is a good case for a RANSAC. Will provide a detailed answer if I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't fit multiple curves on one set of training sets because when you are trying to minimize the cost function there can only be one curve that minimizes it. since you want to fit a curve, there won't be any local optima, and even if you try to sacrifice precision for less time cost running a few times won't give you curves which are noticeably different if they are at all!